# In node js STOMP is not connecting to TIBCO

Tags: node.js, tibco, stomp, kaazing

I am using TIBCO EMS for kaazing. 
Is there any node module like we have for Javascript. (jmsClient.js)? Or is there any alternative way to connect to kaazing in node js.
I see only stomp js in gateway.js provided by Kaazing.